# Is it possible to import “FlatLaf - Flat Look and Feel” into Katalon Studio?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, katalon-studio, flatlaf

Is it possible to import "[FlatLaf - Flat Look and Feel](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/)" into a **test case** of **Katalon Studio**?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add the [flatlaf-2.1.jar](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/formdev/flatlaf/2.1/flatlaf-2.1.jar) file into my project as an external library.

From menu "**Project**" → "**Settings**" → "**Library Management**".

Then I had to import it into my code `import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf`.

And use it like this `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatDarkLaf())`.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]